# I can't add iOS distribution signing identity to my account in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two different profiles with two different Apple IDs in Xcode, first is personal and second is account I use on work.

The thing is, I can normally add iOS distribution signing identity to my personal account. If I delete it, I can simply add it thru Xcode->Preferences->Accounts->View Details->'plus sign'->'iOS Distribution'.
It just works, as it should.

On the other hand, on my business account, I am added to several development teams. On some I am just a member, on some I was added as a member but my rights were elevated to admin, and on some I have been added as an admin right from the beginning.
On none of those teams, using my business account, I cannot add iOS distribution signing identity. Some times, I get an error "Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate" but most of the time it just spins the spinner and does nothing.

Just a note, Apple suggests that "Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate" error happens when you migrate your account from one computer to another, but that is NOT the case here. I am using the same computer all the time - plus - issue is happening from the first moment I was added as a team member/admin to each of those teams.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have finally managed to solve the issue.
What worked for me is:

1. Using keychain, export valid certificate on a computer on which iOS distribution signing identity works. You need two files, one is public - `<fileNamePublic>.pem` file, and other is private - `<fileNamePrivate>.p12` file.
2. Put those files in a folder on computer on which you need signing identity to work.
3. Open terminal and browse to the folder you've put them in.
4. First, type: `security import <fileNamePrivate>.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`
5. Then type: `security import <fileNamePublic>.pem -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`
6. Open XCode, go to XCode>preferences>accounts>view details and refresh the apple id you are using
7. You should have signing identities enabled.

Answer (score 6):

What always works for me if I get code signing identity errors is to...

1.) Sign into the apple id account you wish to use for distribution on the apple developer portal

2.) Go to certificates and generate a new distribution/in-house certificate. You can only have two distribution certs (as far as I know) so you may have to delete one. Make sure this doesn't mess up others using that specific cert if you delete.

3.) Follow the steps to add the new cert to your keychain by 'requesting a certificate from certificate authority'.

4.) Add the newly made certificate to the provisioning profile you will use for distribution.

5.) Go into xCode>preferences>accounts>view details and refresh the apple id you are using

6.) Now when you submit your app for distribution, make sure  your build settings>code signing are set to the correct provisioning profile with the newly added certificate

7.) Go to Targets>project>general and make sure your bundle Id is correct and your team is set to the correct team within the your apple id.

Comment: Your answer is completely valid and procedure you suggest usually solves issues with certificates, but it didn't help in this matter.  
I would, however, upvote your answer for it could help others, but I don't have enough reputation to do that. Once I get more reputation, I will upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using xCode 7.2. On the Account details xCode>Preferences>Accounts>View details... There is option to create one if it's (certificate) not there yet. It will automatically revoke your provisioning profile though. You need to edit and download again from member center.